# Question about statistical notation

Tags: statistics, notation

I am currently reading a paper on statistics (equation 3 in [1](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/bams/97/12/bams-d-15-00267.1.xml?tab_body=pdf)).
There they have the formula:
\begin{equation}
P_{FDR} =  \max_{t=1,...,N}\left[P_{(t)}:P_{(t)} \leq \left(\frac{i}{N}\right) \alpha_{FDR}\right]
\end{equation}

I am not that familiar with the notation, so I want to know how to read it.
My understanding is:
$P_{FDR}$ is the largest value of $P_{(t)}$ that fullfills the requirement of being smaller or equal to $\left(\frac{i}{N}\right) \alpha_{FDR}$.
Is this correct or am I missing something?

Best wishes Akari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just change $i$ to $t$. It is

\begin{equation}
P_{FDR} =  \max_{\color{red}i=1,...,N}\left[P_{(\color{red}i)}:P_{(\color{red}i)} \leq \left(\frac{i}{N}\right) \alpha_{FDR}\right]
\end{equation}

The $i$ on the left and the $i$ on the right refers to the same $i$.

$P_{(i)}$ is sorted and it is compared to $\left(\frac{i}{N}\right) \alpha_{FDR}$, we take the largest $P_{(i)}$ that satisfies the inequality.

Comment: Oh you are totally right about this. I printed the publication and due to the fontsize it looked like it said 't' instead of 'i'. Thanks for pointing this out.
And thank you for the explanation.